# SSD is recognized by linux liveUSB but not by Windows on Asus G73JW laptop

Tags: windows-7, linux, ssd

I have an Asus G73JW laptop, which has two hard drive slots. In the first slot, I have a HDD containing Windows 7. In the second slot, I just inserted an SSD (OCZ Vertex 4) with linux formatting that I took out of another computer.

Now, when looking in the partition manager of Windows, the hard drive was not recognized. And I don't just mean that no drive letter was assigned, the partition manager doesn't see the presence of a disk at all. Installing Ext2Fsd did not resolve this problem.

The BIOS sees the SSD. If I boot my computer with a linux Live USB stick (e.g. Tails), then the SSD is functioning flawlessly and I can access all my data on there. So the hardware is all working fine, hence it must be a problem with Windows.

How can I resolve this problem, and make Windows recognize the disk?

**Edit: never mind, I was mistaken, the BIOS doesn't recognize the disk. Outdated BIOS. Topic closed.**

Comment: Could it be a MBR format like GPT that's confusing windows?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn640535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#gpt_faq_win7_boot Should not be a problem according to the windows help pages...

Comment: I didn't think it would be, but can't think of anything else... Bug in your windows software? Any other disk formatting/partitioning software for windows that might work?

Comment: what do you mean by linux formatting ? ext3/2 ?

Comment: In your question you said multiple times that the SSD is recognized and working without issue. Is your HDD being seen by anything or was this a typo in the question (meant HDD instead of SSD?), please clarify what's happening with the HDD more-so than the SSD, in your question. On the off chance of typos, have you tried removing the SSD and booting with just the HDD in the system as it was before?

Comment: @Daniel No, that's where I looked and it's not showing up.

Comment: @Reeves I'm afraid you misread what I wrote then. The only places where I said the SSD was recognized and working, was in the BIOS and when booting Linux from a Live USB. Under windows it is not recognized. (So I do not see any typo's. The HDD obviously is recognized everywhere, else I won't get into windows.)

Comment: @user1111929 my apologies, I thought the HDD was the issue here, disregard!

Comment: Maybe [firmware update](http://ocz.com/consumer/download/firmware)?
Have you tried IDE and AHCI settings in BIOS?